# How to show value in div id using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I try it. but response is "[object Object]"

```
success: function(data) {    
  var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);    
  console.log(response);
  if (response.confirmation == 'success') {
    $('.std_info').html('<p>Student Name:'+$('#name').val(response.std_name)+'</p>');
  }
}
```

`std_info` is my div id

Comment: Because it's an object, try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` to see it's parameters and make sure it's what you are expecting.

Comment: Or `console.log(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "std_info" is my div id

You need to use `#` for Id not `.`

Use this `$('#std_info')` instead of `$('.std_info')`

> I try it. but response is "[object Object]"

Also another problem is with this line

`$('.std_info').html('<p>Student Name:'+$('#name').val(response.std_name)+'</p>');`

Here the part `$('#name').val(response.std_name)` will set value into the input element with id `name` and **returns you a Jquery object** hence you see the div content as [object Object]

What you need is to simply assign the value from your object . This is your final code

`$('#std_info').html('<p>Student Name:'+ response.std_name +'</p>');`

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

so maybe try `var response = JSON.parse(data);`

also if std_info is the id you should use `$('#std_info')`

Oh - but your biggest problem is this: `.html('<p>Student Name:'+$('#name').val(response.std_name)+'</p>')` you're actually trying to put an object as the content of the div,

try `.html('<p>Student Name: <input id="name" val="'+response.std_name+'" /></p>')` (if I got were you're going with this)

Comment: Yes it's deprecated, although it still functions as of the newest version of jQuery.

Comment: true - but it's deprecated for a reason and no longer supported - why use it in new code?

Comment: which part? what happens? do you still get `[object]` ? can you show what does the `console.log` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 3.0 you should use jqXHR.done() and jqXHR.fail() nstead of `success` and `error`.

More over as of jQuery 3.0 you should use `JSON.parse()` instead of `parseJSON()`. So your call should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'your/url',
   method: 'YOUR_METHOD',
   data: your_data_object
}).done(function(response){
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    if (response.confirmation == 'success') {
        $('#std_info').html('<p>Student Name:'+$('#name').val(response.std_name)+'</p>');
  }
}).fail(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `eval` function rather than JSON.parse.Try..

```
success: function(data) {
var response = eval(data);
console.log(response);
var name=response.std_name;
var success=response.confirmation;
if(success == 'success') {
$('#std_info').html('<p>Student Name:'+$('#name').val(name)+'</p>');
```

Comment: *"Use eval function rather than JSON.parse"*, `JSON.parse` is there for a reason. It would be a bad idea to use `eval` here especially when you don't need to.

Comment: Might be...but i always use eval to operate with ajax returned json array.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that, it's slower and opens up your code to security risk. [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is meant for parsing JSON, you should use that instead.